# Gembird Bleutooth Keyboard connecting but not working

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I just bought a Gembird KB-BT-001-W Bluetooth Keyboard and I can pair and connect with it (after a few tries though, more often than not when pairing, after typing the numeric code it says pairing failed), but none of the keys are working. Except one: the backspace button does work.

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 and I just upgraded to 17.04 to see if that helped. It didn't.

It works fine under windows 10.

Any ideas on how to get the keyboard functioning properly?

Answer (score 0):

It had something to do with the numlock being on.

This solved it for me:

https://askubuntu.com/a/908952/192889